# Generate Controller with composite primary key

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have many tables with a composite primary key in my database. When i generate a controller from my models, i always get methods that only have one parameter. For example:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id = null)
{
    ...
}
```

But what i want to achieve is to get the generated methods in my Controllers with all parameters for the primary key, something like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string pk1 = null, string pk2 = null, ...)
{
    ...
}
```

At the moment i have to change every single controller.
Is it possible to generate this type of controller in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scaffolding template (T4) are located at `[Visual Studio Directory]\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\[MVC Version]\CodeTemplates\AddController`. You can modify or copy these templates and import them in your project and make the appropriate modifications or you can also create brand new ones. Here is [valuable tutorial](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx) on how to achieve this

Answer (score -1):

Using Key attribute when you define your model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace demomvc.Models
{
    public class MultipleKeyModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Key1 { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int Key2 { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int Key3 { get; set; }
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }
}
```